# How to find Itune software is installed in a client browser side?

Tags: plugins, browser

I have a anchor tag with the url "itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movietickets-com-showtimes/id402114309?mt=8".If the client system doen't have the Itune software, then the browser is not opening the page.

Is there any way to know the whether the user installed Itune software or not.

Thanks in advance.

Note:

> If you go to
>   https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movietickets-com-showtimes/id402114309?mt=8
>
> Here you can find or inspect "view in itune" button.There you can see
>   some javascript to detect that.But i dont know what there are doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got a solution,

From the following site https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/movietickets.com-showtimes/id402114309?mt=8

You need to take two js files. (It contains some extra javascript and jquery - you can remove those if you know that it is no longer needed)

1. https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/99EF/web-storefront-base.js
2. https://itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/99EF/web-storefront-preview.js

And you need to add the below code to your page html,

""

Finally, Whenever you want to check the plugin, just call

```
if (its.detect.itunesDetected()) 
{
      //Your code if plugin installed
}
else
{
       //Your code if plugin not installed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple already has code to detect if iTunes is installed, you can find their code here: http://ax.itunes.apple.com/detection/itmsCheck.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is not detecting !

Comment: Would you be more descriptive in how it is "not detecting"?